# How does the referencing work in python and how to create a sperate copy of linkedlist to compare with original linkedlist

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
        regularListHead = ListNode(-1)
        regularListHead.next = head
        reverseListHead = head

        reverseListPrev = None
        reverseListCurrent = reverseListHead

        while reverseListCurrent != None:
            reverseListNext = reverseListCurrent.next
            reverseListCurrent.next = reverseListPrev
            reverseListPrev = reverseListCurrent
            reverseListCurrent = reverseListNext
        reverseListHead = reverseListPrev
        a = regularListHead
```

In my code, I am trying to convert the original list to reversed list and compare both for checking palindrome but when I do the operations to reverse the reverselist then original list is also updated. I am new to python can anyone let me know why this is happening and what could be done to achieve what I want

Comment: There is *only one list*. You are modifying it in-place. You never create a new list, or copy anything. The following should be helfpul: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only create one new node. All the other nodes are the nodes of your original list, and you update their `next` properties so the list is reversed.

So if you want to have *both* the original and the reversed list, you'll have to have two lists, each having their own nodes:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, head: ListNode) -> bool:
        if head is None:
            return
        # Create reversed list
        revHead = ListNode(head.val)
        current = head.next
        while current is not None:
            revHead = ListNode(current.val, revHead)
            current = current.next
    
        # Compare original with the reversed one
        while head is not None:
            if head.val != revHead.val:
                return False
            head = head.next
            revHead = revHead.next
        return True
```

This is however not optimal: the comparison loop should only need to perform /2 comparisons, not .

You may even ask yourself why you would create a *linked* list for the reversed version: as it is only needed for the palindrome check, you might as well create a standard list, and then do the palindrome check with just that list, which is a piece of cake.

But more importantly, creating a new list (whether a linked list or normal "array" list) requires *O(n)* extra space. If you are interested in an algorithm for doing this without creating new nodes, then try to implement this:

1. Count the number of nodes in the list
2. Use that to identify the first node of the second half of the list. If the number of nodes is odd, let this be the node *after* the center node.
3. Apply an in-place list reversal algorithm on that second half. Now you have two shorter lists.
4. Compare the values in those two lists to see whether they are equal (ignore the center node if there was one). Remember the outcome (false or true)
5. Optionally repeat step 3 so the reversal is rolled back, and the list is back in its original state. (This is "nice" towards the caller of your function)
6. Return the result that was found in step 4.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed information. I already implemented the optimal approach similar to what you mentioned. Initially I was just thinking of a brute force approach as my first approach so faced this problem. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: Hi, Any good python tutorials which would clear the concepts in detail like referencing and in general all basics?

Comment: Not sure where to go best. But [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/) helps visualising memory during code execution.